# Array function and slot

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I am trying to make an Array depending on a function, and I saw that `Slot`is useful for my situation. There are examples described in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html?view=all that I'm trying to mimic, but in a more complicated situation.

So, I wrote the following:

`Array[g[Slot[1] / 10 + I*Slot[2]/10,   Slot[3]*10], {10, 10, 10}]`

but instead of actually evaluating the code, it just leaves the Slots unevaluated and just literally prints things like `10 Slot[3] [1, 1, 1]`. This even happens with a very simple function, for instance:

`g[z_, n_] := n`

How can I actually get Mathematica to actually evaluate the slots?

Comment: If you want to learn about programming in Mathematica, I highly recommend [Leonid Shifrin's amazing book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/).

Comment: `Array[Function[g[Slot[1]/10 + I*Slot[2]/10, Slot[3]*10]], {10, 10, 
  10}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [Tutorial: Pure Functions (tutorial/FunctionalOperations#17469)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469) you need to finalize the definition of a pure function using the ampersand `&` character.

For instance, a simplified example would be

```
Array[g[Slot[1]] &, 5]
(*{g[1],g[2],g[3],g[4],g[5]}*)
```

In your case you can do

```
Array[g[Slot[1]/10 + I*Slot[2]/10, Slot[3]*10] &, {10, 10, 10}]
```

Note that `Slot`s are usually written more readably as `#n`, i.e.

```
Array[g[#1/10 + I*#2/10, #3*10] &, {10, 10, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks, missed the & symbols in the examples, and now I see when I put that in, the `#n` actually looks like the green italic font instead of just red font without the & (which is why I used 'Slot' in the first place)

Comment: @Max notice also as mentioned by cvgmt in comments above that you can wrap with `Function` to use the `Slot`s.